# Can I use Tika for content extraction on Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, solr, apache-tika

I'm working on a web service that requires content extraction from uploaded documents (PDF, PowerPoint, Word, etc), and I'd like to host this on Google App Engine to keep costs low. Short of running a Google Compute VM to run Solr/Tika as a server, what are my options? Can I use App Engine's Java hosting to wrap around Tika and return content?

The app flow looks like this:

1. User uploads document. Worker task is placed into queue.
2. Worker task is consumed, triggering sending the filename to Solr for Tika extraction. This process could hypothetically be a Java app reading the file's contents and sending them to Tika.
3. Contents are stored in fulltext search engine and in database.

Using the task queue to execute the Tika command line app does not seem possible.

Answer (score 2):

#### Short Answer:

No not out of the box for much of its functionality.

Too much code relies on `File` objects and creating temporary `File` objects which don't exist in GAE.

#### Long Answer:

It is open source you can hack at the code and change the stuff that calls methods that take `File` objects to take `InputStream` objects instead, and then you can process things that live in the `Blobstore` or `GCS`.

Here is an example I am hacking at now:

```
@NotNull
public static Metadata readMetadata(@NotNull File file) throws JpegProcessingException, IOException
{
    JpegSegmentReader segmentReader = new JpegSegmentReader(file);
    return extractMetadataFromJpegSegmentReader(segmentReader.getSegmentData());
}
```

Where there is this perfectly good call that isn't tied to the `File` object:

```
@NotNull
public static Metadata readMetadata(@NotNull InputStream inputStream, final boolean waitForBytes) throws JpegProcessingException
{
    JpegSegmentReader segmentReader = new JpegSegmentReader(inputStream, waitForBytes);
    return extractMetadataFromJpegSegmentReader(segmentReader.getSegmentData());
}
```